# Reverse characters in words retaining the order of the words

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to reverse the words of *each* word in a string of multiple words. For example:

> "hi whats up" => "ih stahw pu"

This is as close as I have gotten:

```
def backwards(s)
  s.split.each do |y| y.reverse! end
end
```

Thing is this returns an array, not a string. I tried adding `join(' ')` after `reverse!` but that gave me an error.

Comment: Why are you doing this? It sounds like a homework assignment.

Answer (score 6):

```
str.split(' ').map{|w| w.reverse}.join ' '
```

Cleaner version:

```
str.split.map(&:reverse).join ' '
```

Comment: +1 still using `map(&:reverse)` is better I think. Also no need to pass `' '` as argument to split.

Answer (score 6):

Don't know why people insist on using `split`.

```
s.gsub(/\w+/, &:reverse)
```

Comment: Certainly one I wouldn't have thought of, I like it.

Comment: @ŁukaszNiemier For readability, I think using `gsub` is much more straightforward. It expresses the concept directly: "reverse the words". Why do you need to say "split into words, reverse, and join"? Also, it uses less number of methods, which also means it is more direct. As for speed, your version using `split` is faster because you are not giving it a parameter. If you want fine control (i.e., split not just by `" "`), then you need to do `split(/\W+/)` or like that, which makes `split` slower than `gsub`.

Answer (score 2):

You should do:

```
def backwards(str)
  str.split.map(&:reverse).join(' ')
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it right ... You have to call `join(' ')` on the result of the block

```
def backwards(s)
  s.split.map { |word| word.reverse }.join(' ')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to join the result of the `each`, not the result of the `reverse!`. You need:

```
s.split.each {|y| y.reverse!}.join ' '
```